# Issue with loading a 3D mesh with Trimesh

Tags: c++, trimesh

When I load a 3D colored mesh (one RGB color per vertex with the following code :

```
#include "TriMesh.h"
trimesh::TriMesh mesh_true;
if (mesh_true.read("chien/colored/dog_simp.ply")) {
    std::cout << "Number of vertices: " << mesh_true.vertices.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Number of faces: " << mesh_true.faces.size() << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Failed to load mesh file" << std::endl;
}
```

I'm surprised to have the following result:

```
Readin chien/colored/dog_simp.ply... 
Reading 6604 vertices... 
Reading 12999 faces... Done.
Number of vertices: 0 //this is weird !
Number of faces: 0
```

I do not understand why Trimesh is saying that the 3D mesh vertices are of number 6604, while the instruction "  mesh_true.vertices.size() " gives 0.

Any help please ?